# How to execute a Python script on RPi remotely and receive data?

Tags: pi-3, python, networking, ssh

**Question:**

I am trying to run a Python script remotely on my RPi from another python script on my computer.

For now, I have created a local network on my RPi, that my computer can connect to.

I tried to run a subprocess connecting through ssh from my computer:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.call(["ssh","pi@192.168.4.1","python3 /home/pi/desktop/python_server/python_server.py"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
   line = proc.stdout.readline()
   if not line:
      break
   print("test:", line.rstrip())
```

But the script doesn't start and I dont get any data back.

How can I connect remotely to the RPi from my computer and start the Python script?

If possible it would be best if this to be done without manually connecting to a local network first. But I dont know if this is possible?

**Update:**

The process got stuck as it was waiting for me to enter the password to the PI.

How can I avoid entering a password or can Python automatically enter a password to access ssh?

**NOTE**: I would like to access through ssh from any device, so a ssh key between a single computer and the RPi is not an option.

Comment: It is hard to see how this is a Pi problem, especially when the `ssh` command would't do anything on the remote - did you test FIRST before you tried to script  it?

Comment: Hi. I was not aware that the ssh command wouldn't do anything. I thought this was the way to go, so thats what i tested. If there is another way I am open for suggestions. I find it hard as a beginner programmer to find guides and tutorials on this subject.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I generate SSH keys for accessing the Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38649/should-i-generate-ssh-keys-for-accessing-the-raspberry-pi)

Comment: It doesn't really, as I would like any computer to access ssh without performing the sharing of ssh keys first as I state in the "NOTE" in my question. But thanks for the answer

Comment: Why can't you share the SSH keys? There are solutions which forego all security (e.g. telnet), but I really don't see how copying a file to several computers is a problem

Comment: If its just copying/downloading the file to the computer it maybe could work. I would like it to run out of the box as I will have users with computers I dont have access to. I thought the key was unique to the individual computer in which it was created. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Debug that command from a terminal first, before wrapping it into a Python script.

Chances are, `ssh` is stuck waiting for you to type the password in order to login.

There's an [official Pi guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/passwordless.md) explaining how to setup passwordless SSH access on a Pi using private/public SSH keys. You can share the same SSH key across several installations.